# What mod_rewrite rule will 301 redirect /example.html to /example?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to translate or 301-redirect urls such as:

www.domain.com/example.html to www.domain.com/example

Here are the current rewrite rules:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1 [R=301]`

Comment: That partially worked, thank you. Is it possible to create a rule that would cause the end rewrite to be as if the .html was not there? It is interpreting the response differently.

Perhaps I need to modify it to be more similar to this line, where index.php is included?

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Ehm, I'm not sure what you mean. Please give some example inputs and outputs.